# How to get debounce method working in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I am trying to utilise a debounce helper in my LWC code to throttle search queries in my component.

On keyup in the search box I run a function called `searchName`

```
searchName(evt) {
    console.log('search name...');
    let value = evt.target.value;
    this.searchName = value;

    this.debounce(function() {
        console.log('finally reached search method');
    }, 250);

}

debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

Now this should only log the second message after 250 milliseconds but I never get to that point in my component after waiting a few seconds.

Can someone explain why this is not working and what changes I need to make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got this from, but it's simply not right. Most of the logic is wrapped in a function that is then never called, which is why it doesn't work. Instead, you can:

```
timerId;
debounce(fn, wait) {
  clearTimeout(timerId);
  timerId = setTimeout(fn, wait);
}
```

Note that timerId is in the class, *outside* of any function body. If you need an immediate option:

```
timerId;
debounce(fn, wait, imm) {
  clearTimeout(timerId);
  if(imm && !timerId) {
    timerId = null;
    fn.call(this);
  } else {
    timerId = setTimeout(fn, wait);
  }
}
```

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but if this function was in a centralised js file used by various widgets, would the `timerId` be overriden by each call to it?  i.e. if there's multiple LWCs on a screen, each using this debounce function

Comment: @NickCook There's rarely a truly stupid question. Yes, this answer was focused on a single debounce. If you have multiple debounce needs, the timerId should be in a closure. I think the other answer should offer better support for multiple debounces. I should probably add something better to this answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

First create a promise that resolves the timeout, then declares the timerid in the clear as the first steps.

```
  setAsyncTimeout(cb, timeout = 0) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      clearTimeout(this.timerId);
      this.timerId = setTimeout(() => {
        cb();
        resolve();
      }, timeout);
    });
  }
```

call this function with your async function next

```
    await this.setAsyncTimeout(async () => {
      await this.doWork(...params);
    }, 500);
  }
```